# Create a log when user join/abandoned in a og group in Drupal 7

Tags: hooks, organic-groups, log-messages

I'm creating a log with several actions in drupal.

I need register in a custom log when a user requests to join a group. Then I need register that the user has joined in the group or has abandoned this.

Appreciate any guidance to investigate. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heartbeat module](http://drupal.org/project/heartbeat) is the one to try.

I didn't tested it myself, but I read in its description that it's "an API to log activity".

It seems to support OG activity.